# Aligning axes in ggplot2 heat map

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, axes, geom-tile

I'm working on creating some heat maps in `ggplot2` using `geom_tile()`. The data is of peak discharge measurements in two rivers. The x-axis is the day of the year, the y-axis is the year, and the colour is the discharge value:
[image: Figure of resulting heat maps]

Notice that in River 1, the data ranges from 1957 - 2019, while in River 2, the data ranges from 1964 - 2019. That makes the y-axis in the River 1 heat_map more compressed. Is there a way to stretch the River 1 plot and have the two y-axes aligned? That would make the River 1 heat map extend lower in the overall figure. Currently, they are displayed using `ggarrange()`

The data is in two csvs with one column for Date and one column for Discharge.

Here is my code:

```
River1 <- read.csv("~/Desktop/River1.csv")
River2 <- read.csv("~/Desktop/River2.csv")
###format dates
River1_1 <- River1 %>%
  mutate(date = as_date(parse_date_time(Date,"ymd")),   
         water_year = year(date),      
         water_month = month(date),
         water_yday = yday(date)) 

River2_1 <- River2 %>%
  mutate(date = as_date(parse_date_time(Date,"ymd")),   
         water_year = year(date),      
         water_month = month(date),
         water_yday = yday(date)) 

River1_2 <- River1_1 %>%
  group_by(water_year)
River1_2$groups <- cut(River1_2$Discharge, breaks=c(0,0.1,0.2,0.5,1,2,5,10,20,50), 
                        labels=c("0-0.1", "0.1-0.2", "0.2-0.5", "0.5-1", "1-2", "2-5", "5-10", "10-20", ">20"))

River2_2 <- River2_1 %>%
  group_by(water_year)
River2_2$groups <- cut(River2_2$Discharge, breaks=c(0,0.1,0.2,0.5,1,2,5,10,20,50))
    
River1plot <- ggplot(River1_2, aes(x=water_yday, y=water_year, fill=groups)) +
  geom_tile(aes(height=1)) +
  labs(title="River 1", x="Month", y="Year") +
  annotate("text", x=182, y=2002, 
           label="8 YEAR DATA GAP", size=3.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks=rev(levels(River1_2$groups)), 
                    values=c("red", "#4B0055", "#3C3777", "#006290", "#008A98", "#00AC8E", "#25C771", "#A6DA42", "#FDE333")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(1957, 2020, by=5), expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1, 32, 60, 91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335),
                     labels=c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"),
                     expand=c(0,0)) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title=expression(paste("Discharge (",m^3,"/s)"))))+
  theme_bw(base_size=12) +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank())

River2plot <- ggplot(River2_2, aes(x=water_yday, y=water_year, fill=groups)) +
  geom_tile() +
  labs(title="River 2", x="Month", y="Year") +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks=rev(levels(LR2$groups)), 
                    values=c("red", "#4B0055", "#3C3777", "#006290", "#008A98", "#00AC8E", "#25C771", "#A6DA42", "#FDE333")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(1957, 2020, by=5), expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1, 32, 60, 91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335),
                     labels=c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"),
                     expand=c(0,0)) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title=expression(paste("Discharge (",m^3,"/s)"))))+
  theme_bw(base_size=12) +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank())


ggarrange(River1plot, River2plot, ncol=2, common.legend=TRUE, legend="right")
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to provide the `limits = c(1957,2020)` argument to the scale_y_continuous() function. As of now, ggplot only knows the axis breaks, but not how much of it it should show.